# I'm trying to describe a bird hopping from branches to branches

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, phrase-requests, english-to-japanese

Respected readers,

I would very much appreciate your help for this problem,

So, I want to say: 'These birds prefer hopping over flying, so normally you would see them hopping from branches to branches.'

My sentence is: '飛ぶことよりホッピングするが好きなので、普通に...(I don't know)...枝と枝をホッピングするを見える。

I think the second part of the sentence has some major grammar issues... Additionally, I have no idea how to say 'they', as in the birds I'm describing, which is highlighted with the brackets.

Please help me and point out any other mistakes, 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries say "hop" is translated as "ぴょんぴょん跳ぶ"，"跳び回る", "飛び跳ねる".

"they" is translated as "彼ら" and you can say その鳥たちが, or you may omit it.

So I translated it as これらの鳥たちは、飛ぶことよりも飛び跳ねることが好きなので、普通に(日常的に)彼らが枝から枝へと飛び移るのが見えるだろう.

Comment: Thank you so much! Annnd I was wondering whether if I can change the だろう to でしょう? I need to write this formally and apparently だろう is more casual than polite?

Comment: Yes, you can change だろう to でしょう. I think でしょう is a bit more polite and soft than だろう.

Comment: `こられの`  `枝えと` -- んん・・？　スマホの予測変換ミス？